# Word choice: poivre or piment?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, alimentation, biologie, botanique

I am confused about the correct word for *pepper* in French. My reference material for my French course indicates that pepper is **poivre**. My friend, a francophone, however contests that. She says the correct word for pepper is **piment**.

To further add to my confusion, I looked up both piment and poivre in Grand Dictionnaire Hachette-Oxford and these were the results:

> **piment**  *nm*
>
> 1. (plante) capsicum;
> 2. (condiment) hot pepper;
> 3. (stimulation) **du piment** a bit of spice; **le risque met du piment dans la vie** danger adds a bit of spice to life.
>
> **`Composés`**
>
> **piment doux** sweet pepper; **piment rouge** red hot pepper, chilli; **piment vert** hot pepper.

> **poivre**  *nm*
>
> pepper; **poivre moulu** ground pepper; **poivre en grains** whole peppercorns; **poivre blanc/noir/vert** white/black/green pepper; **un steak au poivre vert** a steak with green peppercorns; **poivre de Cayenne** cayenne pepper; **poivre et sel** salt-and-pepper (épith); **il est poivre et sel** he has salt-and-pepper hair; **poivre rose** pink pepper berries.

Note that both entries indicate pepper as possible translations!

This is the pepper I am talking about:
[image: pepper picture]

More images [here](http://www.goodhousekeeping.com/cm/thedailygreen/images/DN/red-pepper-vitamin-c-lg.jpg), [here](http://www.rna-seqblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/chili-peppers.gif) and [here](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1f/Poivrons_Luc_Viatour.jpg).

Comment: Interestingly this confusion is found in Japan as well where the sweet pepper is known as ピーマン (which comes from French "piment")

Comment: Sur la photo, les gros deux fruits orange et rouge sont des poivrons, utilisés comme légume dans les plat méridionaux avec le poivron vert ; ils ne sont pas piquants et ne sont considérés épices dans les recettes de cuisine.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, both translations are right, but the one you show on the picture is indeed '*piment*', the *hot peppers* — the genus *[Capsicum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capsicum)* (as well as *[Pimenta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pimenta_%28genus%29)*). Though, the big ones on that picture, the *pepper bells* are not *piment* but '*poivron*' (species [*Capsicum annuum*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capsicum_annuum)).

The '*poivre*' version of *pepper* is the one that's usually on the table with the salt (grey or black pepper): the 'genus *[Piper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piper_%28genus%29)*'.

And as a note, the *jalapeños* peppers (*piments*) in France is not as widely known as in US or UK, we only differentiate hot peppers by color (*piments verts*, *piments rouges*).

Comment: By color or by origin: _piment d'Espelette_, _piment de Cayenne_

Answer (score 14):

"Pepper" has a few different equivalences in French, depending on what you're referring to. There are basically three different words: *poivre*, *poivron* and *piment*.

*Poivre* is used to refer to the spice. Therefore black pepper will be *poivre noir*. Other examples include *poivre blanc, poivre moulu, poivre à grain entier*, etc.

*Poivron* is used to refer to sweet peppers. In your picture, it would be the big orange one and the big elongated red one, which would usually be called bell peppers.

*Piment* is used to refer to hot peppers. They are also often called *piments forts*. That is also where the adjective *pimenté* stems from, referring to the hot and spicy flavours.

Depending on the region you're in, it's possible that *poivron* and *piment* are used interchangeably. In Québec, for example, *piment* is usually used for most fresh peppers.

Comment: This is correct. _Poivre_ refers to the berries.